# Running gulp-nodemon in gulp v4

Tags: javascript, gulp

I've been reading [gulp-nodemo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nodemon)n but all the syntax is for a previous version of gulp, I'm trying to run it on V4.

This is what I'm running:

```
function watcher (genCSS,js) {
  nodemon({
script: './app.js' ,
ext: 'js scss',
ignore: [ 'public/dist/', 'node_modules/' ],
watch:    [tpath.src.js, tpath.src.scss],
tasks: function (changedFiles) {
var tasks = [genCSS,js]
    })
return tasks
} })
}
```

The error is:

```
Task never defined: function done() {
    d.removeListener('error', onError);
    d.exit();
    return tryCatch(cb, arguments);
  }
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by reading [this issue on github](https://github.com/JacksonGariety/gulp-nodemon/issues/162), you have to export the functions, and add them as strings instead. The code was:

```
function watcher (genCSS,js) {
  nodemon({
script: './app.js' ,
ext: 'js scss',
ignore: [ 'public/dist/', 'node_modules/' ],
watch:    [tpath.src.js, tpath.src.scss],
done:done,
tasks: function (changedFiles) {
var tasks = [genCSS,js]
    })
return tasks
}
```

And now

```
function watcher () {
  nodemon({
script: './app.js' ,
ext: 'js scss',
ignore: [ 'public/dist/', 'node_modules/' ],
watch:    [tpath.src.js, tpath.src.scss],
done:done,
tasks: function (changedFiles) {
var tasks = ['genCSS','js']
    })
return tasks
}

exports.genCSS=genCSS
exports.js=js
```